# Upload bulk Metadata for document in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata, bulk

I have a document library with more than 10K documents in SharePoint Online Environment. Each document is having unique document name 
Now I want to upload metadata of 5 columns in it for each document.

Any suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint cares deeply about the unique document names, but any programmatic updates would require you to also export the IDs so that you can use them for import.

Document metadata can be added very much like you would update a regular list.

Manual options: 
Open each document properties and add the data manually... just kidding.

I would

1. update a few examples manually using the item's edit properties
2. create a view or series of views of the document library that filters to fewer than 1000 documents and shows 100 more documents at a time (These limits are because this process makes SharePoint very busy, and giving it a break will help you avoid frustration and make it easier to track the data errors.)
3. Use the Quick Edit/Datasheet of those views to export example data for the items you updated.
4. Export to excel or copy and paste from the quick edit the entire list to get the exact order of the data in SP
5. Populate a spreadsheet with all the metadata you want to import in the correct format
6. Copy and paste the data into the Quick edit/Datasheet view.

Programmatic solutions are available using javascript or PowerShell, but in my experience would generally take longer than doing the updates using the above method.

Comment: at point 2, how can I filter the view for 1000 document.  When I don't have any metadata present in the library !!

Comment: SharePoint added some on your behalf. You might try filtering on the date added or the created by or the modified by. Alternatively you could create a view that limits at 1k and filter on metadata you have not added yet. As long as the view has data in it, you still have work to do.